# Javascript text input editing: How to turn multiple string text shader in one text input into another representation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, text, shader

So I want to have 2 input feilds, one editable.  I need some script that would turn such shader text input:

```
    #ifdef GL_ES
    precision highp float;
    #endif

    varying vec4 v_color;

    void main (void)
    {
      gl_FragColor = v_color; 
    }
```

into such output:

```
    "#ifdef GL_ES\n"
    "precision highp float;\n"
    "#endif\n"
    "\n"
    "varying vec4 v_color;\n"
    "\n"
    "void main (void)\n"
    "{\n"
    "    gl_FragColor = v_color;    \n"
    "}"
```

(such output can be turned into openGL shader static char* )

So how to create such simple tool with Javascript?

Comment: iterate through each line, check for " at start, if not add one and add \n" at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try regular expressions.

html:

```
<textarea id="text1">#ifdef GL_ES
precision highp float;
#endif

varying vec4 v_color;

void main (void)
{
gl_FragColor = v_color;
}
</textarea>
<textarea id="text2"></textarea>
```

javascript:

```
var text = document.getElementById("text1").value;
text = text.replace(/\n/g, "\\n\"\n\"");
document.getElementById("text2").value = "\""+text+"\\n\"";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t9sgA/1/

Comment: One more update let us call it "Big Iron" - made with CodeMirror script for C like code highlight http://jsfiddle.net/t9sgA/7/