# OpenGL ES 2.0 shader, how is time variable called?

Tags: opengl-es, time, shader, opengl-es-2.0

I try to perform such pixel shader:

```
"#ifdef GL_ES\n"
"    precision highp float;\n"
"    #endif\n"
"    \n"
"   uniform float time;\n"
"       uniform vec2 resolution;\n"
"\n"
"       void main( void ) {\n"
"\n"
"        vec3 rgb = vec3( abs( sin( time / 5.0 ) ), 0.0, 0.0 );\n"
"        gl_FragColor = vec4( rgb, 1.0 );\n"
"\n"
"       }\n"
```

I want it to work [alike this webGL mrdoob sample](http://mrdoob.com/lab/javascript/webgl/glsl/01/) (from black to red). But it seems like time variable here is just 0...(

BTW [sample shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229585/javascript-text-input-editing-how-to-turn-multiple-string-text-shader-in-one-tex) runes as expected.

So is there any "time variable" in pixel shaders for OpenGL ES 2.0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the page source on your first link.  You have to calculate and pass in the `time` value from your host program.

OpenGL ES 2.0 has no notion of time, wall-clock or otherwise.